# | (or operator is not working in the regular expression in C language)

Tags: c, regex

The Or operator (|) are not working in C language Regular expressions, it is always giving output as match , if i give incorrect input also "12" or "123" or c displaying as MATCH. I would request to help in this case.

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <regex.h>
  #include <stdio.h>


   int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ regex_t regex;
        int reti;
        char msgbuf[100];

    /* Compile regular expression */
    reti = regcomp(&regex, "1 | 2c | 3c", REG_EXTENDED);
    if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); return(1); }

    /* Execute regular expression */
    reti = regexec(&regex, "123", 0, NULL, 0);
    if( !reti ){
            puts("Match");
    }
    else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
            puts("No match");
    }
    else{
            regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
            fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
            return 1;
    }

   /* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
    regfree(&regex);

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: There are no standard "C language Regular expressions". Which library are you using?

Comment: Be careful with spaces in regular expressions, all characters in a regular expression are significant. You probably also need to group the sub-expressions as regular expressions doesn't have any kind of operator precedence.

Comment: [No match](http://ideone.com/plXXVZ) with "123". With " 2c ", [there is a match](http://ideone.com/qtSrfl). So what is the problem?

Comment: for "14" also match i got .. tried with "^i$|^2c$|^3$" this is working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `1 | 2c | 3c` matches  `1` in `I have 1 dollar`, but from your comments I see you need to match *whole* strings, not just part of them. For that, you need to use anchors `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) that work only when you use `REG_EXTENDED` flag.

When you use alternatives, you need to either repeat the anchors, or set a group with the help of parentheses:

```
^1$|^2c$|^3c$
```

Or

```
^(1|2c|3c)$
```

These expressions [will safely match whole strings](https://regex101.com/r/iG9tV3/1) like `1`, `2c`, or `3c`.